# OpenAPI discriminator oneOf default

Tags: openapi

Given the following OpenAPI YAML, do we always need to define `petType` while creating `Pet`?

Can I by default create a pet of type `Dog` without specifying `petType`? Is there some way to do this with OpenAPI?

```yaml
Pet:
 oneOf:
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Lizard'
  discriminator:
     propertyName: petType
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> do we always need to define `petType` while creating Pet

Yes. As explained in the [Discriminator Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#discriminatorObject) section of the OpenAPI Specification (emphasis mine):

> a discriminator MAY act as a "hint" to ... selection of the matching schema ... We can then describe exactly which field tells us which schema to use:
> ...
> The expectation now is that a property with name `petType` **MUST be present in ... payload**, and the value will correspond to the name of a schema defined in the OAS document.

Comment: In other words: The API designer decides whether the API server requires the discriminator; and this is particularly advisable for complex schemas.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem myself, and I was able to work out the following solution:

```
Pet:
  x-field-extra-annotation: '@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo(
      use = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
      include = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
      property = "petType", visible = true,
      defaultImpl = Dog.class)'
  oneOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Lizard'
  discriminator:
    propertyName: petType
```

I used 6.0.1 version of the OpenAPI generator.

Just in case, here is the link to the documentation where I found many other helpful solutions:
https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring